# Parse Server Logs in Docker?

Tags: docker, parse-server

So I need to dockerize my parse server for a project and im a bit new to Docker.

I'm used to Heroku where I just could use heroku logs or connect papertrial to see the parse logs to help debug things but I have no clue how to see my parse specific logs when its running in a docker container.

I'm able to do test curl and get data back so I know its working but no idea how to find log data.

Searching around really doesn't lead to any results that are more specific to Docker.  I also tried to figure out how to write to the logs folder but the folder alway seems empty.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker collects the logs of each container from `stdout` and `stderr` of a container. As described in [12-factor application](https://12factor.net/), an application should send its logs to `stdout` (it is standardized by heroku):

> A twelve-factor app never concerns itself with routing or storage of its output stream. It should not attempt to write to or manage logfiles. Instead, each running process writes its event stream, unbuffered, to stdout. During local development, the developer will view this stream in the foreground of their terminal to observe the app’s behavior.

That being said, everything you stream to `stdout` of a container will be stored in `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-json.log` directory. You can see the container id using `docker ps` command. You don't have to see the file always. You can do `docker logs <container-id>` to see the logs stored in the container's directory.

If you **have to** have logs in the filesystem, you can store logs inside the container and mount that directory on your host machine to see log files. You can do something like this:

```
docker run -v <host directory>:<log directory in container> ...
```

Hope it helps.